# How do I find in Java a specific element, for printing, in a list of objects with multiple elements?

Tags: java, json, list, stream, iterator

Long story short I parsed all the json from [here](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts)
into a list of objects. But I'm having trouble trying to find a specific object. With all the examples on searching lists online I can't seem to be able to get it.

I ask the user to input a number into int checkId and checkUserId and then compare it. If it matches it should print out the title.

```java
Iterator < Post > iter = posts.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
  if (Objects.equals(iter.next().getUserId(), checkUserId)) {
    System.out.println("found UserId");

    if (Objects.equals(iter.next().getId(), checkId)) {
      System.out.println("found Id");
      //prints the title of object
    }
  }
}
```

And then I tried to use a stream

```java
List<Post> result = posts.stream()
        .filter(title -> checkId.equals(getId()))
        .findAny()
        .orElse(null);
```

All the code I cloned it from this great guy. https://github.com/danvega/httpclient-tutorial

Comment: save `iter.next()` in a variable, don't call it twice, each call moves the cursor !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first attempt does not work because you are advancing the iterator twice on each iteration by calling `next`. Instead, store the result of `Iterator#next` and use it.

```
Iterator<Post> iter = posts.iterator();
 while(iter.hasNext()){
        Post post = iter.next();
        if(Objects.equals(post.getUserId(), checkUserId)) {
            System.out.println("found UserId");
            System.out.println(post.getTitle());
        }
    }
```

With streams:

```
List<String> titles = posts.stream().filter(post-> checkId.equals(post.getId()))
                        .map(Post::getTitle).collect(Collectors.toList());
titles.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thank you. It was driving me crazy for hours.

Comment: @TerryLight Happy to help.

Comment: With your help I found this to work too.
```
 for (Post post : posts) {
            if ((Objects.equals(post.getUserId(), checkUserId))&&
                (Objects.equals(post.getId(), checkId))) {
                    System.out.println("found UserId");
                    System.out.println(post.getTitle());
                }
            }
```